# Parallel vector resizing not speeding up

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, openmp

I have to my disposal 8 processors.
I wanted to do parallel resizes as follows:

```
    vector<vector <int> > test;
    test.resize(10000);
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0;i < 10000;i++)test[i].resize(500000);
    }
```

I noticed that the program didn't use 100% of processor power - it used only 15%. As I changed the code for

```
    vector<vector <int> > test;
    test.resize(1000000);
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0;i < 1000000;i++)test[i].resize(5000);
    }
```

the program used about 60% of processor power. I don't understand this phenomenon - I hoped it would use 100% of processor power in bogth cases. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Operating system is Windows 10

Comment: Does the behavior change if you do something more CPU-intensive than reallocating a vector? In other words, is it a problem with how you’re using your tools, or does your workload just not benefit much from eight-way parallelism?

Comment: Internal of allocation might require synchronization. allocation is probably not bound by CPU, ...

Comment: Surely you run into memory system bandwidth issues, making such a  comparison of little practical use. If you are trying to get an indication of cache performance by shortening vectors,  it will take more study than I am willing to undertake.

Answer (score 9):

On Windows, the CRT uses the built-in Windows heap implementation, which is single-threaded.

[HeapAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc) locks a CriticalSection (essentially a mutex) for the duration of allocation, essentially sequentializing the allocation process.

Since vector resizing is mostly heap (re)allocation, you will not see much improvement from parallelizing it.

> Serialization ensures mutual exclusion when two or more threads attempt to simultaneously allocate or free blocks from the same heap.
>
> Setting the `HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE` value eliminates mutual exclusion on the heap. Without serialization, two or more threads that use the same heap handle might attempt to allocate or free memory simultaneously, likely causing corruption in the heap.

To benefit from parallel memory allocation, use a different heap allocator. For example [jemalloc](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc).

Comment: glibc on Linux uses a thread-aware allocator by default I believe. ;-)

Comment: Yes indeed, and FreeBSD uses jemalloc :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for but have you considered using boost::multi_array